# ConvLSTM2D initial_state assertion error

Tags: python, keras

I have an issue with [the latest version of Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/2.1.6). I would like to provide an auxiliary input to `ConvLSTM2D` that will act as the initializer of the layer memory.

This feature is supposed to be implemented, however, the following code

```
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers.convolutional_recurrent import ConvLSTM2D

latent_dim, mesh_size = 10, (20, 20)
prior_in = Input(shape=mesh_size + (latent_dim, ))
core_in = Input(shape=(None, ) + mesh_size + (1, ))
core_out = ConvLSTM2D(latent_dim, activation='elu', kernel_size=(3, 3),
                    padding='same')(core_in, initial_state=[prior_in, prior_in])
model = Model([prior_in, core_in], core_out)
```

raises

```
  File "tst.py", line 9, in <module>
    padding='same')(core_in, initial_state=[prior_in, prior_in])
  File "python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional_recurrent.py", line 320, in __call__
    output = super(ConvRNN2D, self).__call__(full_input, **kwargs)
  File "python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py", line 497, in __call__
    inputs, initial_state, constants, self._num_constants)
  File "python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py", line 2247, in _standardize_args
    assert initial_state is None and constants is None

AssertionError
```

On the other hand, this feature seems to be [unit tested](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.1.6/tests/keras/layers/convolutional_recurrent_test.py).

After some debugging, I have found the difference between the code that is unit tested and my code is that `K.is_keras_tensor(initial_state)` is True only for the code posted above. This is important when the program reaches [convolutional_recurrent.py line 313](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.1.6/keras/layers/convolutional_recurrent.py). If I manually disable the if clause by changing the line 313 to

```
if False and K.is_keras_tensor(additional_inputs[0]):
```

The error is not raised and it is possible to train, save, load the model and to use it for prediction without any issues.

The question is: Does anybody observe the same behavior? Do you have any suggestion how to solve the issue on the client side (without modifying Keras source code)? Can anybody explain what is the piece of code in the `if` clause for*)?

*) Looking into [history](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9094), it was copy-pasted from LSTM implementation introduced [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/5795).